# Silverlight Datagrid Styles

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid, styles

I am using a Silverlight Datagrid to produce a dynamically created questionnaire and need to remove all the datagrid styles (this includes any onClick or Hover styles)

Can someone please advise how this is done.

Comment: think you may have to re-style the datagrid with your custom style that overrides all unwanted behaviour

Comment: Is there not a way of just removing all of it as im not aware of the controls i need to excluse and dont have expression blend

Comment: If you want to remove all the styles, why are you using the DataGrid?